# VBA macro in Excel 2007. I want to use Regular Expressions in Excel VBA to replace "He" with "She", "he" with "she", "Him" with "her"

Tags: regex, excel, vba

```
Sub Test()
  Dim strTest As String
  Dim strTemp As String

  strTest = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
  MsgBox RE6(strTest)
  Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Value = RE6(strTest)
End Sub

Function RE6(strData As String)    
     Dim RE As Object 'REMatches As Object
     Dim P As String, A As String
     Dim Q As String, B As String
     Dim R As String, C As String
     Dim S As String, D As String
     Dim T As String, E As String
     Dim U As String, F As String
     Dim V As String, G As String
     Dim W As String, H As String
     Dim N As Integer
     Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")


    P = "(?:^|\b)He"
    A = "She"

    Q = "(?:^|\b)he"
    B = "she"

    R = "(?:^|\b)Him"
    C = "Her"

    S = "(?:^|\b)him"
    D = "her"

    T = "(?:^|\b)Himself"
    E = "Herself"

    U = "(?:^|\b)himself"
    F = "herself"

    V = "(?:^|\b)His"
    G = "Her"

    W = "(?:^|\b)his"
    H = "her"

'This section replaces "He" with"She"
    With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = P
       End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, A)

'This section replaces "he" with "she"
      With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
     .Pattern = Q
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, B)
'
'This section replaces "Him" with "Her"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = R
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, C)

 'This section replaces "him" with "her"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = S
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, D)

'This section replaces "Himself" with "Herself"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = T
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, E)

'This section replaces "himself" with "herself"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = U
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, F)

'This section replaces "His" with "Her"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = V
    End With
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, G)

'This section replaces "his" with "her"
   With RE
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = W '
    RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, H)
    End With

End Function
```

When I run this code on this piece of text:

`James  has settled effortlessly in his new class. He has shown seriousness and demonstrated traits of a serious student in the first half of the term. I am very optimistic that  his positive attitude towards work, if he does not relent, will yield positive dividends. However, James needs to respond positively to prompts on getting himself better organised in school.  I wish Him, him the best in the second half of the term.`

I only get "his" replaced with "her". If I comment out the last bit then I get only "Him" replaced with "Her". Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Any reasons why you use random one-letter names for your variables, making your code very difficult to read and understand?

Comment: Did you ever hear of a **for each loop**, btw? Copy-Paste-orgies like your code are very ugly and error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you repeatedly do your replacement on `strData`, as opposed to the result of each replacement; that is, you take your original string, replace "He" with "She", and then store it in RE6. Then you take your original string again, replace "he" with "she", and then store it in RE6, overwriting the first replacement, and so on and so on.. This is why you only see the results of the last replacement.

To fix it, leave your first replacement as

```
RE6 = RE.Replace(strData, A)
```

but change all of your other replacements to be

```
RE6 = RE.Replace(RE6, B) <-- do this for B-H
```

This will give you your desired output.